# Why does not the EL value display properly in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm currently implements commenting on comments.

But they cause problems.

If you leave a comment on your first comment, it will be displayed well.
However, when you create a new comment, the list of comments that were already created will not be displayed.

The code is shown below.

BoardController.java

```
@RequestMapping("viewPage.do")
public String viewPage(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model, 
        @RequestParam(value="board_idx", defaultValue="0") int board_idx) throws IOException,IllegalStateException
{
    checkLogin(request, response, session);

    int idx = (int) session.getAttribute("idx");
    //System.out.println("idx >> " + idx);

    Board boardData = bService.readBoard(board_idx);
    //System.out.println("boardData >> " + boardData);

    Member memberData = bService.memberNickName(idx);
    //System.out.println("memberData >> " + memberData);

    // Select Comment of Comment List
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> commentList= bService.getBoardForComment(boardData.getBoard_idx());


    // loop (comment.size)
    for(int i = 0; i < commentList.size(); i++)
    {
        int board_comm_idx= (Integer) commentList.get(i).get("board_comm_idx");
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCommentOfComentList = 
                bService.getBoardCommentOfComment(board_idx, board_comm_idx);
        if(!getCommentOfComentList.equals("") || !getCommentOfComentList.isEmpty())
        {
            model.addAttribute("cocList", getCommentOfComentList);
            System.out.println("GetCommentOfCommentList : " + getCommentOfComentList);
        }
    }

    model.addAttribute("boardInformation", boardData); // BoardInformation
    model.addAttribute("memberNickName", memberData); // MemberInformation
    model.addAttribute("commentList", commentList); // CommentInformation
    return "viewPage";
}
```

viewPage.jsp

```
<c:if test="${cocList ne null && not empty cocList}">
                            <c:forEach items="${cocList}" var="cocList">
                            <div class="commentList" style="margin-left:70px">
                            <div class="what">
                                <div class="nickname">
                                    <span>
                                        ${cocList.board_c_of_c_writer}
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="writedatezone" style="margin-left: 715px;">
                                    <span class="era">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time enterReReply"></span>
                                        <span class="commentWriteDate">
                                            <fmt:formatDate value="${cocList.board_c_of_c_writeDate}" pattern="yyy-MM-dd"/>
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="duzone">
                                    <span class="deleteOrUpdateComment">
                                        <a class="updateComment">수정</a>
                                        <a class="deleteComment">삭제</a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            <pre>${cocList.board_c_of_c_content}</pre>
                        </div>
                        </c:forEach>
```

viewPage is a page where you can see detailed information of corresponding post.

The page contains information about the member who wrote the post, information about the post, information about the comment, and information about the comment in the comment.

In my opinion, From BoardController

```
model.addAttribute("cocList", getCommentOfComentList);
```

I think there is a problem in this part.

My comments loop through the size of the commentList, get a list of comments on the comment, and put the lists in the model.

However, in the part where I presented the problem, only the comment value of the last comment I wrote is included in the model.

and, I think each comment list should have a list of comments in the comments.

Do you think my opinion is right? If so, how do I modify the code?

We have not been able to solve this problem and are unable to move on to the next step. Your comments are valuable. Please tell me your opinion. And if you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: TL;DR. Reduce everything to a minimal example reproducing the problem. If the question is about the JSP EL, we don't need to know about your database, your DAOs, etc. We don't need all of your JSPs either. Just a minimal JSP and a minimal controller reproducing the problem.

Comment: If so, what material should I provide?

Comment: Just a minimal JSP and a minimal controller reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet The information is all in my post.

Comment: Maybe, but it's buried inside so many irrelevant information that it's hard for us to even know what the problem is. But hey, you're the one having a problem, and asking us for free help. If you won't collaborate, we won't give a damn. But you will still have your problem.

Comment: @JBNizet OK. I know what you mean. I will modify the question as you wish. But how do you explain JSP? And did the modifications have been modified as requested?